# Journalistic term for front-page promotional strip

Tags: terminology, journalism

The Financial Times, like many other newspapers, has a strip under its title on the front page, split into several items (three in today’s paper — *see* illustration) promoting articles on internal pages. I was wanting to refer to one of these in a letter but realized I had no idea what the technical/journalistic term for it is. There must be one, because people working on the newspaper have to refer to it, but it’s something that is quite difficult to formulate an internet search for. Does anyone know what it is?

[image: Newspaper front page]

**Addendum**

Apologies, but it didn’t occur to me that US journalistic usage may possibly be different from British usage, which is my practical concern in this case. I’ve addressed that myself.

Comment: When viewing the excellent answer by @Josh61 it occurred to me that British professional usage may be different. So I've modified my question to take that into account.

Comment: Can you [edit] this to show a picture of what you're asking about? :)

Comment: See also/CF: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56155/15661

Comment: @curiousdannii — Have done. (Apologies for not doing it originally.)

Comment: @jejorda — I agree, but the problem is that the accepted answer here differs from that in the other question. Can they be merged or is there another way of dealing with the problem? (And my title is snappier ;-) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ***[kicker](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kicker):***

> - ***Also called eyebrow, highline, overline, teaser***. Printing, Journalism. a short line of copy set in a distinctive type above a headline and intended to call attention to it. (Dictionary.com)

[image]

Comment: That's a great picture and answers the question beautifully except for being quite low-res and hard to read.  Can you put up a more high res version by any chance?

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I can't find a higher res picture, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for looking!  it's still quite readable anyway :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer as more of the site's users will be from the US. However I've checked British usage. In British journalism ‘kicker’ appears to be used differently. Three sources — [here](https://www.journalism.co.uk/glossary.php), [here](http://www.thenewsmanual.net/Resources/glossary.html) and [here](https://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072407611/student_view0/glossary.html) — give variants on “The first sentence or first few words of a story's lead, set in a font size larger than the body text of the story.” Of your alternatives, ‘teaser’ and ‘overline’ were not quite on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case when the strip refers to columnists featured in the issue - usually with their photo - I've seen the term **[flannel panel](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1454759/Media-diary.html)** used.

It seems that this term [more generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flannel_panel) refers to the text panel (usually inside, rather than on the cover) that lists publisher and editorial staff - the term 'flannel' in this case meaning flattery, the implication being that there's no real need for the information other than to feed the egos of those listed.

The ultimate flannel panel, then, is one on the front page, with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure that it’s good etiquette, but I thought I ought to do the work and answer my own question in the context of British Journalism. I only found one term (with a variant) and this was in two separate sources:

**skybox** *or* **skyline**

[Guardian/Observer](http://image.guardian.co.uk/sys-files/Guardian/documents/2011/08/26/EducCentNewsterminology.pdf)

> **Skyline** : this is an information panel on the front page that tells the reader about other stories in the paper to tempt them inside.

[The Newspaper Designer’s Handbook](https://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072407611/student_view0/glossary.html)

> **Skyboxes, skylines** : Teasers* that run above the flag on Page One. If they're boxed (with art), they're called skyboxes or boxcars; if they use only a line of type, they're called skylines.

and

> ***Teaser** : An eye-catching graphic element, on Page One or section fronts, that promotes an item inside; also called a promo.